# How to get the sum of the absolute value of data in a column in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

How can I select the sum of the absolute value of a column in a `DataTable`. I can use a select statement such as:

```
SELECT sum(abs('Position')) FROM 'MyDb'.'MyTable';
```

on a database table. How can I do that on a `DataTable` in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Cast to an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and use linq

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
var amounts = rows.Select(r => Maths.Abs( (int) r["Position"] ));
var sum = amounts.Sum();
```

and chained:

```
return 
 table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
 .Sum(r => Math.Abs( (int) r["Position"] ));
```

Comment: Can you explain why the `Cast` and `ToList` are nessasary? (not saying they aren't)

Comment: the `Cast` is, to get it into an `IEnumerable` so you can do linqy-poos on it. the `ToList` is only needed when you want a concrete list - it forces an enumeration of the expression and returns the results.

Comment: Ahh, I was confused becase `Cast<>` itself is an `IEnumerable` extension method. But `Sum` extends `IEnumerable<TSource>`. Get it now.

Comment: Took liberty of updating your code and comments after you took out the `ToList` also `Sum(a=>a)` can just be `Sum()`, or you can just put the select predicate right in the `Sum`.

Comment: what is meant by and chained?

Comment: because many linq expressions return the same IEnumerable<T> these methods can be "chained" - joined together without the need to form new variables. e.g. Select().OrderBy().Take().ToList()

Comment: There's a typo, `Maths.Abs` should be `Math.Abs`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Double sum = 0;
foreach(DataRow row in thisTable.Rows)
{
    sum += Math.Abs(row["Position"]);
}
```

Comment: I like this because it is straight forward and relies more on c# than linq or sql; it gives me ideas on other calcs I'll be doing with other columns in the DataTable.

Comment: If this is the answer then please check it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need for linq. Can use [Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method.

```
dt.Compute("SUM(Column1)", "Column1>0")
```

Full working example:

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
            dt.Columns["Column1"].DataType = typeof(Int32);
            dt.Rows.Add(1);
            dt.Rows.Add(2);
            dt.Rows.Add(-1);
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("SUM(Column1)", "Column1>0"));
            Console.WriteLine(a);  //Will print 3
```

Comment: I am adding both positive and negative numbers hence the use of Abs. It looks like this would only sum the positives. In your example code my desired result would be 4.

Comment: This post is older than dirt it seems but @user1819133 is correct that this isn't the desired result. I tried something similar but attempted 'dt.Compute("SUM(ABS(Column1))", string.empty)' to try and return the correct value and received this error "Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier." And now I'm here looking for the correct solution which thankfully exists. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a year late, but it might be useful to others.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Type = i.GetType
tbl.Columns.Add("abs", t, "(iif(col<0,-col,col))")
Dim sumAbs As Integer = tbl.Compute("sum(abs)", "")
```

The ABS function is not supported, but you can DIY with IIF.

Also, you must do the calc in two stages. First make a column with the IIF logic as it's expression, then sum the new column.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Int64 total = datatableName.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<Int64>("yourcolumn"));
```

Please check for your desired datatype if some issue let share here the above give you sum of negative and positive numbers both.

Comment: I don't think you read the post correctly. The OP is looking for a sum of the absolute value of the column values, not just a sum.